# Appium node.js server can not start: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: android, windows, node.js, android-studio, appium

I try to Launch Appium 1.3.7 version on windows, to inspect my app's elements, etc. but this is what I get everytime

```
>     > Starting Node Server
>     > info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode
>     > info: Pre-launching app
>     > error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT
>     > 
>     > 
>     > Node Server Process Ended
```

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\

Path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Is something wrong? how to get rid of it. help please.

Comment: Check your %PATH% or %JAVA_HOME% environment variables, it seems that your appium does not see the java, and can't start it. Or try to find out the requirements about java version for your appium current version. Maybe your current version is not compatible with your java.

Comment: No, everything is okay with the path. and also there is nothing wrong with jrk1.8.0_40 and appium 1.3.7.1 too

Answer (score 0):

Install latest java from official site and make sure you have set the environment variable from My computer, properties,Advanced System settings, Environment Variables and add  JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75, den try

Comment: this is my JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\

and this is my Path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

is something wrong ?